# Why can't I overwrite protected methods to public in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

To my knowledge this doesn't break Liskov's Substitution Principle as an instance of a subclass can do all the things that an instance of a superclass can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that might be true, but it's something that as3 can't do regardless.